# Spotlight bug / Mac App Store

Tags: mac, spotlight

When I search for the Keynote app using `spotlight` there is a reference of a previous version on the Mac App Store.

[image]

However, when I press on it, I get the following error message:

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely it is a previous version on your Time Machine drive.

Open system preferences > spotlight > privacy

Drag the Time machine drive into that window so it won't show results from that drive.